# LocalNotification / Reminder PhoneGap plugin for WebOS?

Tags: cordova, webos

Is there a LocalNotification PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin for WebOS ?

It can send a reminder notification at the specified time even if the App is not running.

```
plugins.localNotification.add({
        date : new Date(2012,6,10),
        message : "Phonegap - Local Notification \r\n -- For WebOS",
        ticker : "This is a sample ticker text",
        repeatDaily : false,
        id : 4
});
```

It exists as a PhoneGap plugin for [iPhone](http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=84) and has been ported to [Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification).

If no PhoneGap plugin exists, what would I need to do to build one? I could use 
`Mojo.Controller.getAppController().showBanner`
and [Alarms](https://developer.palm.com/content/content/api/reference/services/alarms.html) to create some Javascript functions such as:

- addAlarm
- cancelAlarm
- cancelAllAlarms
- localNotification
- ...

Any other ways to do this or sample code which accomplishes something similar for webOS?

I'm a fairly experienced programmer but brand new (2 days) to webOS and the Mojo framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some information in setting up alarms in Mojo applications:

http://webos101.com/Alarms

You'll want to look at the information on multi-stage applications as well.  I'm not sure how easily it can be converted into a simple plugin but the functionality can be easily created.

Comment: Thanks for the link. In my case I probably want wakeup:false.

If I want to have multiple timers set, I can just set multiple keys:

    key: MyAPP.appId + '_' + myId + '.sync'

Comment: Do still need to use a multi-stage application if I just want to call "showBanner" and re-launch the application if it is not currently running when the banner is clicked?